# laravel 4.2 update multiple models

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to update multiple models like this:

```
$value = $model->collection;
if(count($value))
{      
  $prices = $collection->prices()->update(['price' => 'price' * 5]);
}
```

? or I need to do something like this:

```
if(count($value))
{      
   $prices = $collection->prices;
   foreach($prices as $price) {
     $price->price = $price->price * 5;
     $price->save();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the documentation for `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`: https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html

**There's no method to update all results in a collection**, but there are methods to iterate over every item, within which you can do whatever you need. Perhaps something like...?

```
$collection->each(function($model) {
    $model->price *= 5;
    $model->save();
});
```

Your second code example looks almost correct, except that there's no `prices` property available on the collection. You simply iterate over the collection itself. This is equivalent to the code above:

```
foreach ($collection as $model) {
    $model->price *= 5;
    $model->save();
}
```

And if the `price` field is [mass assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment), it's perhaps more readable as:

```
$collection->each(function($model) {
    $model->update(['price' => $model->price * 5]);
});
```

---

Lastly, if the operation you want is possible in SQL, you could combine `modelKeys()` from a collection with `whereIn()` on the query builder for a one-liner (although not necessarily recommended):

```
$model->whereIn($model->getKey(), $collection->modelKeys())
      ->update(['price' => \DB::raw('price * 5')]);
```